# Unusable desktop in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, nautilus, gnome-classic, thunar

I am using Ubuntu QQ with `gnome-session-fallback` for a long time now. I replaced **Nautilus** with **Thunar** but when I restarted the laptop, the panel works, but I cant right click or change the desktop background.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replaced Nautilus with Thunar (How?), there is no desktop because Nautilus draws the desktop, so if it's not running you don't have a desktop.

So run it (you will get a Nautilus window though). Or, use `xfdesktop` to draw the desktop and replace Nautilus for this task and keep Thunar.